# VIM: Underline enclosing parentheses

Tags: vim, vi

I know i can highlight matching parentheses in VIM.

Is there a way to underline enclosing parentheses like Sublime does?

Only the 2 parentheses around the cursor without having the cursor on one of them. Example:

[image: Vim highlight surrounding parentheses]

Comment: I'm not sure what it would look like but % will already take you to the first enclosing paren - so there's definitely a way

Comment: Example? Is this as simple as underlining the parens instead of highlighting?

Comment: I would also be happy with highlighting the enclosing parentheses without moving the cursor on one of them.

Comment: Example http://i.stack.imgur.com/1mtZD.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlights the pair surrounding the current cursor position.
https://github.com/Yggdroot/hiPairs

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the default plugin for highlighting matching parentheses is enabled, then it should be as simple as adding a few styles to the `MatchParen` highlight group:

```
highlight MatchParen term=underline cterm=underline gui=underline
```

More help on the highlight command:

```
:help :highlight
```

Comment: That seems to only highlight the parentheses when my cursor is on one of them not between them.

Comment: If you really want to highlight them constantly, then you can do `match MatchParen /\v[\(\)\{\}\[\]]/`  That will use the MatchParen highlight group to color all parentheses.  However, this is really more of a color scheme thing, so it isn't really a feature of sublime text, it's just part of whatever theme you are using.

Comment: This still isn't the behavior i want. It should only highlight the 2 parentheses around my cursor. Not all of them.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood you.  I don't think that is possible in a short one-liner.   You can try https://github.com/kien/rainbow_parentheses.vim though.

Answer (score 0):

These plugins highlight the pair of parentheses surrounding your current cursor position:

- https://github.com/justinmk/vim-matchparenalways
- https://github.com/Yggdroot/hiPairs
- [ShowPairs](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=626)